# SharePoint 2016 August CU

Tags: cumulative-update

Does anyone face any issue updating the August 2019 CU for SharePoint Server 2016? I have May 2019 update applied on our servers, but checking if you need to update to August 2019. Thank you in advance for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I installed in our test farm and no issue found. But again the practice is apply the cu in lower environment then test it as per your functionality requirement.

their is no harm to keep the farm up to date.

**Issue:** one user report the issue related to "missing all custom managed properties in the Sort-Dropdown in the Query Builder (Search Result Webpart)" 
https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2019/08/13/august-2019-cu-for-sharepoint-server-2016-is-available-for-download/

Again testing is key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.